# How to rollback RBS and what happens to existing data

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, rbs

Let's say I am using Remote Blog Storage (RBS) in one of my content database and decide not to use anymore.

1. How can I roll back RBS?
2. What will happen to my data and how can I migrate it out of RBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can disable Remote BLOB Storage (RBS) on any content database. After you disable RBS on a content database, binary large objects (BLOBs) are stored inline in SQL Server for all subsequent writes to the content database. This article describes how to disable RBS on a content database.
2. you data will be fine, instead of using of RBS it goes back to inline in SQL Server. To Disable the RBS on a content DB use this powershell.

   $site=Get-SPSite "http://yourSiteURL"
   $rbss=$site.ContentDatabase.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
   $rbss.SetActiveProviderName("")

[Disable RBS on SharePoint 2013 content databases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628259.aspx)
[Migrate content into or out of RBS in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628254.aspx)

Comment: This TechNet article answers my second question. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628254.aspx

Comment: So if I'm understanding the TechNet article correctly, to get existing RBS content back into SQL, you have to run the powershell script to migrate it?

Comment: that's correct.